# What is the proper behaviour of seekp in the context of beyond the file

Tags: c++, fstream

What should be the content of the file after executing following code

```
int main (int, char**) {

    std::string s1 {"Hello world"};
    std::string s2 {"x"};

    std::fstream f {"file1", std::ios_base::out};
    f.write (s1.data (), s1.size ());
    f.seekp (10, std::ios_base::end);
    f.write (s2.data (), s2.size ());

    return 0;
}
```

I mean what should be placed between 'old' end of file and 'new' end of file. I changed write cursor position beyond end of the file. So, what characters should be used as fulfillment.

After execution it, I read the file using cat, vim and Kate. Outputs are:

```
Hello worldx                       # cat
Hello world^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@x   # vim
Hello worldx                       # Kate**
```

** in the text editor between d and x were a lot of whitespace characters. Kate showed the description that this file contains invalid characters.

Comment: I think this is implementation-dependent in the C++ specification. On Unix, the gap is filled with null bytes, which is what you see in `vim`. Try `cat -v` to see non-printing characters with `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

First the good news:

What's happening on your system is probably what you'd expect - 10 bytes of value zero are being written into your file to fill the 'gap' (or perhaps they were already zero in the memory page and this was just luck).

`^@` is shorthand for `CTRL-@`. In the ASCII system the CTRL key subtracts decimal 64 from the ASCII code of the key you pressed. `@` is ASCII code 64 or 0x40.

Now the bad news:

The c++ standard has nothing to say on the matter, and neither do the underlying C APIs. So what you're doing is probably not portable - unless you don't care about the values of those bytes.